# Vertx JDBCPool java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am executing a delete query using `vertx` `JDBCPool.preparedQuery.execute` like below,

```
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM demo_table WHERE id = ?"
JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx,config); //config has only standard parameters like host, port, credentials
pool.preparedQuery(deleteQuery).execute(Tuple.of(id));
```

And I am getting below error, but the record was deleted from table

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getObject(SQLServerResultSet.java:2174) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar:?]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getObject(NewProxyResultSet.java:217) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.lambda$parse$0(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:43) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.convertNumber(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:225) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.decode(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:80) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.parse(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:43) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCQueryAction.decodeReturnedKeys(JDBCQueryAction.java:209) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCQueryAction.decode(JDBCQueryAction.java:76) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.execute(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:71) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.execute(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:39) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCConnectionImpl.lambda$schedule$3(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:219) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159) ~[vertx-core-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100) ~[vertx-core-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157) ~[vertx-core-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76) ~[vertx-core-4.2.0.Beta1.jar:4.2.0.Beta1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
 [vert.x-worker-thread-4] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils - tx.id= Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: null; errorCode: 0]
```

If I change preparedQuery to query method it is working perfectly.

I gone through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425280/2151491 , but in my case it is not a multiple connection problem.

Vertx version - 4.2.0.Beta1

JDBC version- mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7

DB - MSSQL 2014

Please let me know what could be the issue here?

As suggested by tsegismont, I upgraded vertx to 4.3.5, but the issue is not resolved, below are the log lines

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getObject(SQLServerResultSet.java:2174) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar:?]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getObject(NewProxyResultSet.java:217) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.lambda$parse$0(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:62) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.decodeNumber(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:217) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.decode(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:89) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.parse(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:62) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCQueryAction.decodeReturnedKeys(JDBCQueryAction.java:195) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCQueryAction.decode(JDBCQueryAction.java:72) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.execute(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:64) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.execute(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:44) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
```

Comment: `4.2.0.Beta1` is an old and pre-release version. Can you try with, for example, `4.3.5` ?

Comment: Hi @tsegismont I tried upgrading to 4.3.5, since Hazelcast(used in vertx) 4.2.5 is having vulnerabilities not able to download, can I upgrade Hazelcast to 5.0.3  and test?

Comment: You can upgrade Hazelcast to 4.2.6 but not 5

Comment: I am not able to download 4.2.6 either, the least version available in my company repo is 5.0.3

Comment: @tsegismont, please see my edit, vertx upgrade also didn't work

Comment: Then please share a small reproducer on GH or Gitlab and file a bug.